# Get Max Row by Column and Date Range

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm trying to get a unique list of rows based on a column and a date range from another column.  Here is example data:

```
id      CustomerNum    ServiceDate
------------------------------------------------
4406290 000000000066    2017-02-17 13:03:00.000
4406294 000000000066    2017-02-17 13:07:00.000
4406295 000000000066    2017-02-17 13:09:00.000
4406295 000000000066    2017-02-09 13:09:00.000
4406352 000000000066    2017-01-17 13:12:00.000
4406369 000000000066    2017-03-17 13:16:00.000
4582381 000000ABC102    2016-03-22 14:48:00.017
4589037 000000ABC102    2016-07-23 14:54:11.223
4625101 000009983148    2017-03-30 15:21:11.283
4625162 000005555398    2017-01-30 11:22:20.907
4625165 000005555398    2017-03-30 12:22:20.907
4625168 000005555398    2017-03-30 15:22:20.907
```

I need to group by CustomerNum and then by ServiceDate but only if the ServiceDate is within 7 days.  I'd like to have the max (latest) row by grouping.  So the results should be:

```
id      CustomerNum    ServiceDate
------------------------------------------------
4406295 000000000066    2017-02-17 13:09:00.000
4406295 000000000066    2017-02-09 13:09:00.000
4406352 000000000066    2017-01-17 13:12:00.000
4406369 000000000066    2017-03-17 13:16:00.000
4582381 000000ABC102    2016-03-22 14:48:00.017
4589037 000000ABC102    2016-07-23 14:54:11.223
4625101 000009983148    2017-03-30 15:21:11.283
4625162 000005555398    2017-01-30 11:22:20.907
4625168 000005555398    2017-03-30 15:22:20.907
```

I've tried the following:

```
WITH cte
AS (
SELECT *
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        PARTITION BY CustomerNum ORDER BY ServiceDate DESC
        ) AS rn
FROM CustomerTransactions
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
```

but this gives me row numbers over all CustomerNum instead of starting row number over at 1 after date range has been met.

I know I'm missing something.  Any thoughts?  Thank you.

Comment: what do you mean by `only if the ServiceDate is within 7 days`?

Comment: For instance, if customer 11111 had a service date of 01/07/2017 and one for 03/07/2017, they both are unique rows but if they had another for 03/08/2017,that falls within 7 days of 03/07/2017 so that is not a unique result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this problem, you want to use `lag()` and cumulative sum.  Use lag to determine where each group starts, then cumulative sum to assign the groups:

```
select sum(case when prev_ServiceDate > dateadd(day, -7, ServiceDate) then 0 else 1 end) over
           (partition by CustomerNum order by ServiceDate) as grp
from (select ct.*, 
             lag(ServiceDate) over (partition by CustomerNum order by ServiceDate) as prev_ServiceDate
      from CustomerTransactions ct
     ) ct;
```

You can then summarize the groups using aggregation:

```
select CustomerNum, min(ServiceDate), max(ServiceDate)
from (select sum(case when prev_ServiceDate > dateadd(day, -7, ServiceDate) then 0 else 1 end) over
                 (partition by CustomerNum order by ServiceDate) as grp
      from (select ct.*, 
                   lag(ServiceDate) over (partition by CustomerNum order by ServiceDate) as prev_ServiceDate
            from CustomerTransactions ct
           ) ct
     ) ct
group by CustomerNum, grp
```

Comment: With a few tweaks, this worked like a champ.  Thank you!